# Does applying a function to a random variable never affect the probabilities/expected value?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

Assume we are on the discrete setting.

The expected value of a random variable $X$ can be expressed as $P^TV$ where $P$ is the vector of probabilities of $X$ and $V$ are the corresponding values $X$ can attain.

Then is seems to me that the following should be true:

$$E[f(X)] = P^Tf(V)$$

For any $f$. Is it true?

Comment: yes, by your own definition

Comment: I did not define the expected value I gave a formula that calculates the same number. I don;t know if the formula generalizes to other cases.

Comment: that one is the definition for any discrete random variable. Notice that $f(X)$ is also a discrete random variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you define $f(V)$ to be a vector whose $i$th element is $f(V_i)$ where $V_i$ is the $i$th element of $V$, then your claim is correct and follows from [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).